# How to change the width and the height of a table by using \adjustbox?

Tags: tables, tabularx, width, adjustbox, resize

I built a table by using `\tabularx` in a `\landscape` environment. I want to resize this table by `adjustbox`.

I used \adjustbox, it can resize the height but the width is still the same. I used this

```
\afterpage{
\newgeometry{margin=5pt}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table} [ht]
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\centering
\scriptsize
\scriptsize
\makegapedcells
 \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{adjustbox} {center,%
     max width=1\textwidth,
    max totalheight=0.97\textwidth}
<<Table>>
\caption{Table}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

}
```

This is the picture of the result,
[image]

How to fit a large table in this page ?

Comment: resizing tables should be a last resort and even then don't do it it forces inconsistent font sizes and rule widths. As you are using tabularx anyway why not specify the table is the width you want without needing to scale it?

Comment: note that you want to use `\linewidth`  not `\textwidth` to get the width in landscape but if you specified that to tabularx adjustbox will do nothing.

Comment: If you want to overlap the margins, that is a separate issue.